# Why it isn't working? I have seen examples using this, but when I use it, it crashes. Why?(C)

Tags: c, graph

Why can't I do `g->n=n` ? Can someone explain?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 100000

int N[]={100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000};
double B[]={0.125, 0.250, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.750, 0.875};

typedef struct Graph
{
    int n;
    int M[MAX][MAX];
    int val;
    int adjacent[MAX-1];
}G;

struct Graph * RandomDirectedGraph(int n, double b)
{
    struct Graph * g = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    g->n=n;
    int u,i,v;

    for(u=0;u<n;u++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            g->M[u][i]=0;
        }
    }


    int m=b*n*n;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        do
        {
            u=rand()%n;
            v=rand()%n;
        }
        while(u==v || g->M[u][v]==1);
        g->M[u][v]=1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,b;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(N)/sizeof(*N);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeof(B)/sizeof(*B);j++)
        {
        RandomDirectedGraph(N[i],B[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it, ERROR pops up and says that some memory can't be written. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You're trying to allocate 37 gigs of memory. You probably just got 0 from malloc.

Comment: Ok, but how do I change that? How do I initialize the pointer g?

Comment: Aside: Simplify `g = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));` to `g = malloc(sizeof *g);`.  Will not solve key issue here, yet cleaner code.

Comment: "how do I change that" You would have to rewrite `struct Graph` such that it  doesn't use a  matrix of 10,000,000,000 integer elements to represent a graph on 3 or 300 or 3000 vertices. At a bare minimum, try redefining `MAX` such that it is not 100 times larger than the maximal value you actually use, thus `M` is not 10,000 times larger than it needs to be. Additionally you may save up to 4x more memory by changing the type of `M` to either `char`, `int8_t` or `bool`. Unfortunately a thorough explanation of better methods would entail writing a sizeable portion of a C programming textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that everytime you are executing the method RandomDirectedGraph, your application tries to reserve about 40GB of RAM memory. I guess your computer doesn't have that much.

Furthermore you should release all memory by calling free on the pointers.

For such big matrices, you don't use classic C matrices. You need external librarys for sparse matrix calculations like https://www.alglib.net/matrixops/sparse.php

Comment: So what do I do to prevent that? Do I change the type of function?

Comment: I am actually not sure what your code should do. Your implementation doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: @DanielWiechetek how would change the type of function reduce the size of memory you want to allocate? Your `struct Graph` is a huge monster with a gigantic array of 10^12 integers. Rethink your approach and come up with an algorithm that does not need that much elements in the array.

Comment: @DanielWiechetek: Please provide us the reference code that your ones is based on. Maybe we can explain why it behaves different.

Comment: I got it. I just changed my 'MAX' variable value, because I didn't need to allocate so much space and it worked. Thanks.